# Can I tell when I earned a specific hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash

I came back from 2 hours away from keyboard and discovered I earned a new hat.

Is there a way for me to tell EXACTLY when the hat was awarded?

Let's assume there's no way to deduce this based on hat's semantic meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no way. While we do store that information, we don't expose it anywhere.

It wouldn't be very precise anyway, because hats are awarded in five-minute intervals.

Comment: I can totally live with ~5 minutes inaccuracy. Maybe a tooltip over the snowflake menu items? (as adding "[x] ago" won't fit in the one line for each item)

Comment: Agreed. 5 mins is 100 X better than couple of hours.